# vue3 ssr does not return plain html

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, server-side-rendering, quasar-framework

I'm using quasar and vue3 to build an SSR app

In chrome developer mode when I visualize the generated HTML, I have some Vue components not compiled to raw HTML like:

```html
<body class="desktop body--light" data-server-rendered>
<div v-for="deal in clientssList" :key="client.Id">
  <CLientItemSmDown :ClientModel="deal"></CLientItemSmDown>
</div>
```

is this normal, isn't SSR supposed to return raw HTML so bots can read it?

Comment: SSR is not supposed to do that no, it's just meant to run your code on the server and generate something more friendly to crawl than an SPA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saw this question last time already (can't find it back).

But no, `CLientItemSmDown` is a valid [web-component](https://javascript.info/custom-elements) and don't **need** to be transformed into a built-in HTML tag like `input`, `div` etc...
There is maybe an option to convert it down the road to some HTML, but I don't think that it's necessary and it may not be easily done if it's not supported by default.

That page may be quite interesting regarding [Vue + Web-components](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html).

You may raise a [Github issue](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/new/choose) or join [their Discord](https://discord.gg/qK43xUjR).

---

The TLDR being that it's fine to let it as is IMO.

Comment: is that the also for css, because i dont see any styling in the page ?

Comment: @lzaek that is a broad question. What do you mean exactly? The CSS is applied and visible with the inspector no? Using SASS or anything similar? CSS needs to be vanilla in your page or some classes on the tags with a CSS stylesheet imported at the top.